# How to Pass the value in bytes32[] array

Tags: solidity, remix

Given this constructor:

```
function Voting(bytes32[] candidateNames) public {
    candidateList = candidateNames;
}
```

How to pass pass the value in the parameter `candidateNames` when I deploy the contract in remix?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Did you try entering any value in the textbox infront of `Deploy`?

Comment: yes i am giving candidateName but it gives an error.

Comment: Can you please update the question with what you tried and what is the error you got?

Comment: Rohit Sahu try it by using hexadecimal notation.
means to say include 0x with input. i think it'll run. so try it.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add an example of the input? Remember that the constructor parameter is an array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're willing to do a little text editing, here's a mostly painless way. Make new a contract (or temporarily add the function below to this contract and pass `[]` to the constructor when you run it). Hardcode the candidate names (note that I set the array size to 3 since I know it for this example):

```
function getBytes32ArrayForInput() pure public returns (bytes32[3] b32Arr) {
    b32Arr = [bytes32("candidate1"), bytes32("c2"), bytes32("c3")];
}
```

Compile and run the function. You should get this output:

```
0x63616e6469646174653100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x6332000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x6333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Then use a text editor to format it like this:

```
["0x63616e6469646174653100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x6332000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x6333000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

It's now in the proper format so that Remix will accept it in the constructor text field as `bytes32[]`.

Comment: To compile this we need to tell the compiler to look in memory for the bytes array. The code would be updated like E.g. (bytes32[3] memory b32Arr)